# Problems on scanning for Bluetooth Low Energy signals in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to develop an app capable of detecting Bluetooth Low Energy Signals and thanks to an Adapter, show it in a Listview. At the moment has worked perfectly but now what I want to do is the onLeScan method so that when the scan has found a device, it compares the device and the rssi value with all the elements of the list. If both parameters are the same as the one of the items of the list, it doesn't  call the adapter to add the device found. However, when I compile the code, it detects the BLE signals but the rssi value doesn´t changes.

Here is the code I used:

```
// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int size = leDeviceListAdapter.getCount();
                        for(int j = 0 ; j < size ; j++) {
                            BluetoothDevice devices = leDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(j);
                            Integer signal = leDeviceListAdapter.getRSSI(j);
                            if (devices!=device && signal!=rssi){
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        leDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device, rssi);
                        leDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                    }
                });

            }
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Please Help!!!! If it is necessarily I will put the whole code.

Comment: Your program logic is faulty - if your heard signal does not match any one in your list adapter, you return before adding it.

Comment: then how can I correct it? Can you put the right code? Please!!

Comment: Add logging to the program logic so you see what it is doing, and think about how it needs to change.

Comment: sorry for the inconvinience but I haven´t understand it. Can you repeat it with more details. How I can solve it??

Comment: can you put the correct code in an answer please??!!!!!